# Adding a Icon to notification area in android app

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-mediaplayer

O.K i have looked around this site and others and i see something similar to what i am wanting but yet it isn't what i am wanting...let me explain
i am learning to build an android app using eclipse that has a media player linked to my shoutcast server i am running, so far the apps works great but it doesn't have an icon on the top were the notification area is and when i go to a different app  (a game) to play while leaving the music playing it minimizes the app .. thats fine but when i reopen the app it doesnt stop the mediaplayer infact if i play the player i will have 2 players running i will then have to force stop it using the task manager,, i know this can be done as i have apps on my phone that has icons and it will do what i am wanting
when i searched this site i found a link to youtube that has soemthing similar to what i am wanting
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e74z0_Z5QWI&feature=relmfu the code that is shown is as followed

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class StatusBar extends Activity implements OnclickListener{

NotificationManager nm;


@Override
Protected void onCreate(bundle savedInstance){
//TODO Auto-generated method Stub
    super.oncreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statusbar);
    Button stat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStatusBar);
    stat.setOnClickListener(this);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
public void onClick(View v){
//TODO Auto-generated method Stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StatusBar.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

}
```

i have add this code to  my MainActivity.java but it spits several errors to me that i have tried to fix using quickfix here is the script i currently have in my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.myapp.mytapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{
    private Button btn_play,
    btn_pause,
    btn_stop;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private int lengthOfAudio;
private final String URL = "http://link to url:8002";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable r = new Runnable() { 
@Override
public void run() {
updateSeekProgress();                   
}
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
init();
}

private void init() {
btn_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
btn_stop.setOnClickListener(this);
btn_stop.setEnabled(true);

seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
btn_play.setEnabled(true);
btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
SeekBar tmpSeekBar = (SeekBar)v;
mediaPlayer.seekTo((lengthOfAudio / 100) * tmpSeekBar.getProgress() );
}
return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

try {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
lengthOfAudio = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
} catch (Exception e) {
//Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
}

switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.btn_play:
playAudio();
break;
case R.id.btn_pause:
pauseAudio();
break;
case R.id.btn_stop:
stopAudio();
break;
default:
break;
}

updateSeekProgress();
}

private void updateSeekProgress() {
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / lengthOfAudio) * 100));
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
}

private void stopAudio() {
mediaPlayer.stop();
btn_play.setEnabled(true);
btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
btn_stop.setEnabled(true);
seekBar.setProgress(0);
}

private void pauseAudio() {
mediaPlayer.pause();
btn_play.setEnabled(true);
btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
}

private void playAudio() {
mediaPlayer.start();
btn_play.setEnabled(true);
btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
btn_stop.setEnabled(true);
}

public void homepage (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://myhomepage.com/");
}

private void goToUrl (String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}

}
```

here is what is in my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    startForeground()>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                   <Button
            android:id="@+id/homepage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:onClick="homepage"
            android:text="Home Page" />



        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:src="@drawable/play" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/pause"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pause" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/stop"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:src="@drawable/stop" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" >
    </SeekBar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scast" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/version" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

can someone tell me what i did wrong or can rewrite what i have and still keep everything working
Thanks in advance
Rob

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know how to make a notification icon, or do you want to know why it is opening another media player

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, yes i am wanting to know how to make the app icon appear in the notification area, however since you brought it up id like to know why its opening another player instead of opening the active player

Comment: For the icon, check Google's documentation on notifications, it's very helpful.

Comment: thankyou for the reply again,, i am looking at the google docs for the notifications, i have read this before but im not sure witch one to use as (from what i understand) this is to set up notification to the user to receive an email of some sort, what i am wanting is it to be a static image that is shown when app starts and not shown when app stops, i am not wanting to email the user or anything, unless i am misunderstand it, i am new to the scripts so i am a noob to it,, can you show me using my code above by adding what i need., thanks

Comment: The user doesn't receive an email, the notification is dumped into the tray, where the user can either dismiss it or act upon it.

Comment: So i add the following to my java? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification after add that what would i add to my main activity

Comment: You have to try to understand the documentation at least a little bit. Don't come here, look at the methods in the reference. They do a pretty good job of explaining everything. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: while i do understand the docs i do know how to read and got the idea on how things work  however it doesn't make me ask questions on it, please don't be rude by telling me to not come here that i just asked a question, i thought that was what this site was about is to get answers to questions if you get stuck.... now back to topic having read all that and adding this code http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification to my java what do i add to my main layout.xml

Comment: That's the beauty of `NotificationManager`, all the code you really need are those first few lines. Setup your `Builder` object using the methods provided, and then use `NotificationManager.notify()` to present it.

Comment: OK still stuck on this i have tried pretty much everything and results either it doesn't show the icon on the notification tray or it force closes i add this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification to java and add this NotificationManager.notify() (what jeeter suggested) to my main layout.xml unless i am doing it wrong i cant figure it out,, sorry for being a pain about it, could someone please tell me the correct way to have a icon appear in the notification area when my app starts and it disappears when i close the app that's all i want ty